# Dynamically Add button from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-layout

i am working on an app in which, button Onclick dynamically created a button  from one activity and button is appeared in another activity.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: i have two activities and when i am in second activity here a button is clicked which create a button in main activity.

Comment: Do you want it to return to the main activity?

Comment: yes exactly i want this

Answer (score 0):

So, for your button, see the code below. I'm just using `SharedPreferences` for testing if button has been clicked before or not.

```
// Inside your onCreate() method of your SecondActivity.java
((Button)findViewById(R.id.activity2_button)).setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("ShowButton", true).commit(); // put Boolean inside SharedPreferences
        Intent main = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(main);
        finish();
    }
 }
```

And now, the `FirstActivity.java` code :

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1_layout);
        if (getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("ShowButton", false))
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.activity1_button)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.activity1_button)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Test it, and tell me if this works great. Hope it will work for you, Darkball60 :)

Comment: it will not work for me i have written some code but it works when i create button in second activity from first activity. but this is not working from second activity